# absolutely convex ideals and $F$-spaces.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm asked to prove this:

> $X$ is an [$F$-space] if and only if every ideal is [absolutely convex]

I have a problem in proving the first direction that if $X$ is an $F$-space then every ideal is an absolutely convex one.

> **F-space:** (the topological concept) F-space is a *completely regular* Hausdorff space for which every finitely generated ideal of the ring of real-valued continuous functions is principal, or equivalently every real-valued continuous function f can be written as $f = g |f|$ for some real-valued continuous function $g$.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, an $F-$space is a vector space. But to talk about ideals, it seems like you want $X$ to have a ring structure. Is this right? If so, what are the continuity requirements on the ring structure?

Comment: I mean the topological concept F-space which is a completely regular Hausdorff space for which every finitely generated ideal of the ring of real-valued continuous functions is principal, or equivalently every real-valued continuous function f can be written as f = g |f| for some real-valued continuous function g.